# Search lines of textfile between two words, that contains a keyword

Tags: java, text-files, keyword

I have to extract lines from a textfile that contains a keyword, delimited by two words.

I've already found only the line that contains keyword (with `contains(string)`) , but I need to have also a pair of lines before and after this, maybe not counting the lines, but searching the first and the last word of this group of lines.

How I can do that?

Comment: can you post an example of your textfile? Also can you show what you have done already?

Comment: Is an xml file, to read like a simple text file. I've to extract content between two tags, essentially ;) but into this tag ther must be a particular word that I've found with the following code: BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathFile)); String line = in.readLine(); while (line != null) {
                if (line.contains(str)) { 
                   ....

Comment: then i would suggest you using daniel's example, as it simply does what you need.

Comment: Dunno, beacuse the keyword appears in the text more than once :(

Answer (score 1):

You could store the lines in a java.util.List in the first step and then iterate over the list with an index.

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
while(reader.ready()){
  lines.add(reader.readLine());
}

for(int i = 0; i<lines.size();i++){
  if(lines.get(i).contains(string)){
    String lineMinusTwo = lines.get(i-2);
    String lineMinusOne = lines.get(i-1);
    String line = lines.get(i);
    String linePlusOne = lines.get(i+1);
    String linePlusTwo = lines.get(i+2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But if I can extract text's lines without counting it, but only searching by first and last word is  better!

Answer (score 0):

How about implementing a "VERY ROUGH" lexer that reads the lines and maps them into a HashMap. The integer would be the line number and the string the whole line.
Process the whole file and then loop through the map when you find a line that has the keyword you can go look up the previous n lines that you need based on the current line number and the next n lines as well.